# Who should the beta moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderators

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice. [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer**. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- **Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged**. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of Windows Phone.SE who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

It's also good if the moderators:

- Are members with participation in both meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com and windowsphone.stackexchange.com.
- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

*After the site graduates from beta, elections will be held to choose moderators. For the beta period, Stack Exchange staff will decide who the moderators are, but it's best if volunteers put themselves forward and receive a favorable community response.*

Comment: How many moderators should Windows Phone Stack Exchange have?

Comment: @VitorCanova per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/ `Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections after the Beta period.`

Answer (score 7):

[profile for Joe on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/23930.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/23930)

I'm willing.

I am very interested in seeing this site grow and expand the collective Windows Phone knowledge base. I committed to the proposal back in Nov 29 '11, and signed up either the same day, or the day after private beta started.

You can check out my [meta participation](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/users/131/joe), and my [main site](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/131/joe).

Answer (score 2):

[profile for Tom Wijsman on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/19908.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/19908)

*Joe*

I nominate [Tom Wijsman](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/users/25/tom-wijsman) [[Main]](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/25/tom-wijsman). He has been one of the more active members on both meta and main.

---

*Tom Wijsman*

Thank you for nominating me, I accept and am aware of what is expected from a moderator.

As I've used old phones for a long time like the SE K750i, the LG Cookie and some Windows Mobile that wasn't that impressive; I finally got around on buying a Windows Phone. But because it's so costly, it would be a waste not using the most out of it. And that's why I think keeping up to track with this community is very handy for, learning about new stuff on the Windows Phone that's out there while trying to help people solve their problems. For example, just learned about the new Photosynth app yesterday.

Besides that, I really like to contribute and help to form and maintain communities that interest me. Adding questions on meta where they miss, joining in on discussions / support. Not to forget participating on the main site whenever I can.

One of the first was [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/666/), I left behind a big pile of questions there to poke the scope of the site, that was a hard time were [defining subjectivity and enforcing rules](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) to bring the site on the right track. Since then the site became more expert, and it wasn't kind after the thing I joined the site for.

Then came [Productivity.SE](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/users/141/) which I spent  quite some time on, but despite [some attempts](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195/call-to-action-ask-more-questions-broaden-our-scope) at getting the community on a positive trend it kinds of sticks there because while it is interesting to spent time on making yourself productive it isn't really that popular so the scope is kind of too small. So, I feel that I can't do more than hope to one day [revive that community](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40223/life-improvement) in a way that hopefully works...

During these I've also been present at Guitars.SE, Audio.SE and Video.SE, later these became Music.SE and AVP.SE. Had some interest in music those days and tried to get some questions that were on my mind answered.

Last but not least, the main site I've been visiting every day; is [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/9666/) ([Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/users/9666/tom-wijsman)), because I like troubleshooting computer problems. People that want to see more about me can visit my [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/19908/tom-wijsman) and my [earlier nomination at SU](https://superuser.com/revisions/234915/23) from a year ago.

Thank you for your consideration and I promise I would do my best to help this community.

Feel free to use the comment section below if you have questions...

Answer (score 2):

[image: profile for row1 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I am a new Windows Phone user. I had previously done a lot of development work on Windows Mobile and am now looking forward to seeing where the Windows Phone platform heads.

I don't have a large history on Stack Exchange but I am currently an active member on this site and am very interested in sticking around for the duration of my Lumia 800 and beyond. I do currently [run a support forum](http://simple-review.com/forum/index.php?action=profile;u=1) and also have a somewhat related [blog](http://row1.info/).

Thanks for your consideration,

Rowan.